# How to add conditions in Vue JS when populating data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

So i have a table that populates data, this is the code:

```
<tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
   <td>{{user.id}}</td>
   <td>{{user.name | upFirstLetter}}</td>
   <td>{{user.email | upFirstLetter}}</td>
   <td>{{user.role | upFirstLetter}}</td> -- Basically user role has two types (Admin, Customer)
<tr/>
```

My problem is that it populates all the user but I want it to only show the user with a role of 'Customer'. I'm still learning Vue, Thanks in advance.

Comment: The current answers are both correct until you clarify your question: You want to show id, name, email of non-customer users? Or your aim is fully filtering them out?

Comment: It was to fully filter them out. I checked one from the both as he also pointed out the right approach for filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-v-if), you can combine v-for with v-if, so add a v-if clause to your first line:

```
<tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id" v-if="user.role == 'Customer'">
```

EDIT:
In the documentation [it is pointed out](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential) that you should instead compute a list of Customer users and iterate over that list instead

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the row even if the user role is not customer you can use a condition in your td element. This is useful if you have still other columns that are important to show instead of not showing the row at all. Do not forget to add a v-else with a td element so that the same amount of td elements are provided in a row.

```
<td v-if="user.role="customer">{{user.role | upFirstLetter}}</td>
<td v-else>/<td>
```